# How to print the only the tbody of table html using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

[jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/acselv96/jcspxdgy/8/)

```
<table border="1" cellpadding="3" id="printTable">
    <tbody id="printTbody"><tr>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>      
        <th>Points</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Jill</td>
        <td>Smith</td>      
        <td>50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Eve</td>
        <td>Jackson</td>        
        <td>94</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>        
        <td>80</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Adam</td>
        <td>Johnson</td>        
        <td>67</td>
    </tr>
</tbody></table>

<br />
<br />

<button onclick="printTablefun()">Print Table</button>
<button onclick="printtbodyfun()">Print Tbody</button>
<script>
function printTablefun()
{
   var divToPrint=document.getElementById("printTable");
   newWin= window.open("");
   newWin.document.write(divToPrint.outerHTML);
   newWin.print();
   newWin.close();
}

function printtbodyfun()
{
   var divToPrint=document.getElementById("printTbody");
   newWin= window.open("");
   newWin.document.write(divToPrint.outerHTML);
   newWin.print();
   newWin.close();
}
</script>
```

### Description

1. From this above link i have added the fiddle like and the code

### Problem

1. When i click the "Print Table" button its printing the properly as a table
2. When i click the "Print Tbody" button its just printing only the text but in table format

### What I needed

1. When i click the "Print Tbody" button have to print the content in the tbody as in a table format

### While clicking "Print Table" button

[image: While clicking "Print Table" button]

### While clicking "Print Tbody" button

[image: While clicking "Print Tbody" button]

Comment: Wouldn't printing the tbody correctly have the same result as printing the whole table? Since there is no thead or tfoot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say the behavior you describe and show in screenshots is correct. a `tbody` element without a parent `table` element should be interpreted as text since it marks some rows of a table as body/content of the table and without the table there is no body.

for testing purposes just remove the `table` tag from your html code and view it in your preferred browser. the output is just text (at least for me in chrome)

if you want the output to be a table, declare it as table:

```
function printtbodyfun()
{
   var divToPrint=document.getElementById("printTbody");
   newWin= window.open("");
   newWin.document.write("<table>"+divToPrint.outerHTML+"</table>");
   newWin.print();
   newWin.close();
}
```

as an alternative, you could try to add css to the output window and change the `display` css value of the tbody to table.

EDIT:
didn't got the css solution to work :/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide an element on printing you can use `css` solution by using `@media print`

```css
@media print {
  .hide-on-printing {
    display: none; // hide the elements have this class when document is being printed
  }
}
```

```js
class Print {
  constructor(elem) {
    this._elem = elem;
    elem.onclick = this.onClick.bind(this);
  }

  print() {
    let newWindow = window.open('');
    newWindow.document.write(`<table>${table.outerHTML}</table>`);
    newWindow.print();
    newWindow.close();
  }

  table() {
    this.print();
  }

  tbody() {
    thead.classList.add('hide-on-printing');
    this.print();
  }

  onClick(event) {
    let action = event.target.dataset.action;
    if (action) {
      this[action]();
    }
  }
}

new Print(actions);
```

```css
@media print {
  .hide-on-printing {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<table border="1" cellpadding="3" id="table">
  <thead id="thead">
    <tr>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>Points</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="tbody">
    <tr>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Eve</td>
      <td>Jackson</td>
      <td>94</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>Doe</td>
      <td>80</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Adam</td>
      <td>Johnson</td>
      <td>67</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<br />
<div id="actions">
  <button data-action="table">print table</button>
  <button data-action="tbody">print body</button>
</div>
```

P/S: I tried to print on current tab it works but not when click button.